# Which music proram am I hearing?

Tags: music

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04. I seem to have accidentally started one of the music programs, but how do I stop it? It doesn't show up in any window. I could run **ps**, I suppose, but I doubt if I could interpret its output.

Comment: The `pacmd list-sink-inputs` might offer a bit too much information, but anything playing audio would appear in the output 

Comment: This seems to have worked for me.